# .htaccess is being ignored in one subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, debian

I have been looking around for hours now and can't seem to find a solution, so time to ask a question.

I got a .htaccess file that is being ignored in a specific subfolder. All other .htaccess files work as they should in their respective folders. I got no specific rules set up for the folder.

The .htaccess file contains **Options -Indexes**

The root folder is a Magento webshop and the folder in question is two subfolders down.
**root/shop/colors/**  *(colors is the bugged one)*

I got a exact copy of the folder structure and files but with different names and that .htaccess works.
**root/test/colors/**

So why is one .htaccess being ignored but not the rest?

Comment: What tells you that `shop/colors/.htaccess` is being ignored

Comment: What's the contents of the htaccess file(s) in the parent directories?

Comment: Because it lists all files in that folder. The parent htaccess got the same "Options -Indexes"

Comment: Is there anything in your vhost config for the `/shop/` or `/colors/` directories? Like a `<Directory "/path/to/shop/colors/">` or something?

Comment: No, it only contains config about the root. And it got AllowOverride All

Comment: And your browser isn't showing you a cached page? Because even if the htaccess file in "colors" is completely ignored, the parent htaccess contents get applied to it, and if it also says "Options -Indexes", then something's not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index.html in the bugged folder where cached and use a manifest file. When i cleared it with chrome://appcache-internals/ It started to work.

So why does appcache prevent .htaccess files?

Comment: Because it's your browser (chrome) that's caching, and it's not the htaccess file's fault. See: http://appcachefacts.info/ because it's cached, chrome isn't sending the server a new request.